# Bubble Sort help + capturing Print into variable

Tags: r

Hello I am trying to make an early finish bubble sort function.
I need to print number of swaps + number of times the function vector.bubbleup was called. This is my code

```
vector.swap <- function(vector,index1,index2){
  temp <- vector[index1]
  vector[index1] <- vector[index2]
  vector[index2] <- temp
  return(vector)
}

vector.bubbleup <- function (vector) {
  index_start <- 1
  index_end <- length(vector) - 1
  swap <- 0
  for (index in index_start:index_end) {
    if (vector[index] > vector[index+1]) {
      vector <- vector.swap(vector,index,index+1)
      swap <- swap + 1
    }
  }
  print(swap)
  return(vector)
}


vector.bubblesort <- function(vector){
  iteration <- length(vector)-1
  while (iteration > 0){
    vector <- vector.bubbleup(vector)
       iteration <- iteration - 1
    }
  return(vector)
}
```

Lets say I have a vector with the values 66 11 44 88 47 36

The output of vector.bubblesort will be

```
[1] 4
[1] 2
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 0
[1] 11 36 44 47 66 88
```

All of the numbers before the vector is the print function used in vector.bubbleup, but how do I record them and how do I count the number of times the function was used.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The number of swaps and the number of `bubbleup` calls can be stored in a variable. Just declare

```
nbSwaps <- 0
nbCalls <- 0
```

outside your functions, and add the correct amount to them each time you call the function e.g. `nbSwaps <- nbSwaps + swap` and `nbCalls <- nbCalls + 1`

Comment: I'll have to keep track of swaps in the 2nd function I think. I need a way to add them up in the 3rd function.

Comment: If you declare the variable outside of any of your functions you can modify them in any function you want.

Comment: I got the code to work, all I had to do was turn that whole script into one function and that is all.

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it. I fear however, that making the whole thing into one function is bad practice, since you won't be able to re-use the subfunctions as you had in the original script.